# ExpressJS App with aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I had downloaded the skeleton NodeJS app from [skeleton-navigation download](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/releases/tag/1.0.0-beta.1.2.5)
And I'm using the skeleton-es2016 sub-project. This project includes lots of dependencies, includes browser-sync, testing, gulp, jspm packages and what not. 
I wanted to know if there are any resources for creating a very simple expressJS app. Where I can just include what is needed for a SPA ? Something on the lines of an AngularJS project, where I need to include the core and add any additional packages as an when I need it..

Comment: check out my template here, its a bit more stripped down than the skel nav: https://github.com/Foursails/sentry

Comment: Looks good.. Let me check it out